# What does this error message mean in gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Can anyone give advice on debugging why this command isn't working on MacOS Catalina?

```
~ $ gsutil cp -r gs://elium/photo.video/ /Users/alex -v
CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
```

- /Users/alex is definitely an existing folder

Comment: This might be better off at superuser.com or [unix.se]

Comment: Are you trying to download files or copy between buckets? What are you expecting the ending `-v` to do because that is definitely not a folder

Answer (score 4):

You have the token `-v` at the end of your command, and gsutil thinks that is the destination path. When you provide multiple args to `gsutil cp`, it thinks all args except the last arg are sources (the objects/files to be copied), and the last arg is the destination (the folder/bucket to copy the files into).

The `-v` flag should go **before** all of your non-flag arguments. Try using `cp -r -v`.

Answer (score 1):

@mhouglum was right!

Also, I'll add that the trailing slash in the source URL broke things silently. (I ran the command but got no output)  The final working cmd was:

```
gsutil cp -r -v gs://elium/photo.video /Users/alex
```